# python regex that can traverse single IPs and IP address ranges

Tags: python, regex

Attempting to regex the ability to provide multiple ip address ranges and single IPs. for example the string can contain any number of single IPs or range of IPs such as

example 1

```
ip=10.10.10.3,10.10.10.20-80,10.10.10.4,10.10.11.100-200
```

or it could contain just one IP

example 2

```
ip=10.10.10.5
```

I am able to figure out a regex when i know exactly how many IPs or IP ranges i am supplying. where i am lost is how do i build a regex so that it can except ANY number of IPs AND IP ranges without knowing how many will be supplied ? i could have 4 like in example 1 or even up to 10 different combinations.

UPDATE:

based on the replies i got this final regex working :)

```
ip=(\d+(?:\.\d+){3}(?:-\d+)?,?)+
```

this captures it fine at least in an online regex tester, but online tester i had defined a group match which i see :) that shouldn't matter i would think in the end because i am still getting my full match i needed ??

```
Match 1
Full match  0-50    `ip=10.10.10.3,10.10.10.20-80,10.10.10.4,10.101.1.2`
Group 1.    40-50   `10.101.1.2`
```

Comment: Don't throw Regex at everything, please. Use appropriate parser.

Comment: Haha, that ^. But to answer your question, `r'\d+(?:\.\d+){3}(?:-\d+)?'`

Comment: Put the regex for one IP or IP range in a group and repeat one or more time the group with a + modifier after the right parenthesis

Comment: @coldspeed thanks :) see my update i think i took your feedback and added to it and i think what i have will work even though it has a group match it is still finding a full match correct me if i'm wrong pls :)

Comment: If you want the different addresses in separated groups you can create a capturing group around the regex of a single address inside the main group  ie :((\d+(?:\.\d+){3}(?:-\d+)?),?)+ or you can split the string of the full match with comma as separator, the last solution could be easier to manage

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you replace "ip=" with nothing, and just do a split string on the comma?

```
ip = "ip=10.10.10.3,10.10.10.20-80,10.10.10.4,10.10.11.100-200"


def get_ips(ips_list):
    return ips_list.replace("ip=", "").split(",")


print(get_ips(ip))
```

Either that, or, if you really need regex for it:

```
import re

ip = "ip=10.10.10.3,10.10.10.20-80,10.10.10.4,10.10.11.100-200"


def get_ips_with_regex(ips_list):
    return re.findall(r"([\d.-]+)", ips_list)


print(get_ips_with_regex(ip))
```

Not the most verbose regex, but if you know you are only passing it IP's, it will do the job